# multicollinearity in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multicollinearity

Which is the best way to check for multicollinearity between two binary explanatory variables in logistic regression..? I use SPSS, if anyone could answer with special regards to that programme it would be extra helpful!

Comment: Note that the candidate for duplicate had a misleading title, as "dependent" really meant "independent". (Further ammunition for a personal campaign that these terms are past their sell-by date.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use R? You can quickly explore data by using [CORRPLOT](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html)

Also running a [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) would be helpful to see how much redundancy/multicollinearity are in your features.

Finally, you can try to fit with a linear model and check if the data matrix is full rank / invertable.